# What is the probability of getting a sum of 7 or at least one 5 when you roll two die

Tags: probability

Please tell me how to approach this problem.

(Sum of 7) = {4+3, 3+4, 6+1, 1+6, 5+2, 2+5} = 6
 (At Least one 5) = {1+5, 2+5, 3+5, 4+5, 6+5, 5+1, 5+3, 5+4, 5+5, 5+6} = 10

so the answer will be 16/36 = 4/9 ?

Comment: This is correct.

Comment: You approach is fine. You have just double-counted something. You should get $15/36$.

Comment: @Squirtle is it 15/36 or 16/36?

Comment: No! You absolutely need to count $2+5$ AND $5+2$, because the die act independently of each other.... its not like if one possibility exists the other doesn't.  Its like say, because I can first roll two then five, then it is never the case that if I roll five that I may roll two.

Comment: @LordSoth Yes I double counted 2+5 thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You double counted some possibilities (the two events are not mutually exclusive!). By taking the union of the sets of desirable outcomes, we obtain:
$$ \left\{\begin{align*}
&(1,5),(2,5),(3,5),(4,5),(5,5),(6,5),\\
&(5,1),(5,2),(5,3),(5,4),~~~~~~~~~~~(5,6),\\
&(1,6),(6,1),(3,4),(4,3)~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
\end{align*}\right\}$$
so the probability is:
$$
\dfrac{15}{36}=\dfrac{5}{12}
$$

Comment: This is the correct answer....  I had misread what the question was asking for.

Answer (score 0):

List and count, as described in the other answers, is the best approach. If you want to use some symbolic machinery, let $A$ be the event "sum of $7$" and let $B$ be the event "at least one $5$."

We want $\Pr(A\cup B)$. By a perhaps familiar formula, we have
$$\Pr(A\cup B)=\Pr(A)+\Pr(B)-\Pr(A\cap B).$$

You know how to compute $\Pr(A)$ and $\Pr(B)$. The event $A\cap B$ happens if we get $(2,5)$ or $(5,2)$, so has probability $\frac{2}{36}$.

An alternate version uses the following counting formula:
$$|A\cup B|=|A|+|B|-|A\cap B|.$$
Here by $|C|$ we mean the number of elements in the set $C$.